# Serializing Supporting Classes VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization

I'm starting to learn about `serialization` in the `.NET` framework, but was unable to find what you're supposed to do for properties which return either a custom collection or a custom class object. Say in the example below, my `Items` property returns the custom collection. Do I need to add a 'datacontract` attribute to that class as well?

Also to change it up slightly if any property returns a custom class type, then you must mark all those classes with `datacontract` (and `datamembe`r if they have properties)?

```
<DataContract()> Public NotInheritable Class MyMainClass
Private pFilters As MyCustomClass

<DataMember()> Public ReadOnly Property Items As MyCustomCollection
    Get
        Return pFilters
    End Get
End Property

Public Class MyCustomCollection
    'Stuff in here
End Class
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually a strong divide between "lists" and "everything else". Lists are usually processed purely by looping over the items inside them, via the IList(-of-T, optional) and IEnumerable(-of-T, optional) APIs. So no, lists don't usually require special markers **as long as** they are obviously lists. Domain entities (the "everything else"), however, do usually need to be understood - meaning "yes, it will want attributes".